# Move CSS menu to right of screen?

Tags: html, css, menu, position

Im looking to reposition this drop down menu so that it is at the right side of the title, instead of its current location directly below it. I can't find the code in the css anywhere that is tying it to the left side of the screen?

[image]

index:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Baking</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>I want to bake </h1>

<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">...</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Bread</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Brownies</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Cake</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>ETC</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheet:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #1F2E2E;
}
h1
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:right;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#EEEEEE;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:55px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"ADAM.CG PRO";
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#354343
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0;
    background:#1F2E2E;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:450px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is position:right? Delete this string and change your float:left to float:right

Comment: There won't be code by default to make things left aligned.. as this is default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```css
body 
{
    background-color: #1F2E2E;
}
h1
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    float:right; /* changed to right */
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#EEEEEE;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:55px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"ADAM.CG PRO";
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">...</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Bread</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Brownies</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Cake</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>ETC</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

You have set `float: left` instead `right` to your `#primary_nav_wrap ul`

Comment: Thanks all for your help, it still needs a lot of tweaking but I can work on that!

Answer (score 0):

Change `float:left` to `float:right` in your `#primary_nav_wrap` CSS.

Floating elements left or right, will align them, and break away from displaying as block elements.

But by default, and in regards to your question.. by default, all HTML items are left aligned, unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #1F2E2E;
}
h1
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;



    margin-top:-100px;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#EEEEEE;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:55px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"ADAM.CG PRO";
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:right;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#354343
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0;
    background:#1F2E2E;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:450px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

[DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/jhtnnbrv/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your title at left and menu at right side of the webpage, you can use float.

If you want to have your menu next to your title, you should make them both `display: inline-block;` so they will be in the row.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4L2t3gr/