# How to move this menu bar to the right

Tags: html, css, menu, blogs

I want move objects to the right but don't know how!? Any idea?
. Please help me. Here is the code in HTML and CSS

```css
/*=====================================
= Top Bar
=====================================*/
#top-bar {
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #888;
    font-size: .857em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}


.top-nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.top-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.top-nav {
    font-family: "Montserrat",Open Sans,Sans-serif;
}

.top-nav ul li a {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: .917em;
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-size: .917em;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}


.top-notification {
    float: right;
}

.top-notification p {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.top-notification a {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    padding: 5px 9px;
    line-height: .917em;
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-size: .917em;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    margin-left: 22px;
 background:#fff;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 }

nav ul li a:link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: #fff;
 width:100%;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #fff!important;
}

nav a:hover { 
     background-color: #2da399; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1000;
background: #494949;

}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 min-width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: #656565;

}

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
nav li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
nav li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }


.menu {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
     z-index: 99999;
    background: #2da399;
}

.menu.cloned {
    width: 100%!important;
    left: 0!important;
}

.menu.cloned nav {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

Here is HTML codes for my website. I think every thing in is fine here and the problem is in CSS codes.
```

```html
<!--Main Navigation-->
<div class='menu-wrapper'>
 <div class='menu'>
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/kontakta-mig.html'>Hem</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nyheter </a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/afghanistan.html'>Afghanistan</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/sverige-och-e.html'>Sverige</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Världen</a></li>
            </ul>        
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Vetenskap
</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
              <li><a href='https://www.facebook.com/thevoiceofafghanistan/'>Kemi
</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Fysik </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Matte</a>
             <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Matte 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 3</a>
                        <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Matte 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Hjälpmedel
</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>فناوری </a></li>    
            <li><a href='#'>اجتمائی </a></li>
   <li><a href='#'> سیاست</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>تاریخ </a></li>
   <li><a href=''>کلاس ها</a></li>
   <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/'>صفحه اصلی </a></li>        
  </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
  </div>
```

[This is menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnkct.png)

Comment: We need to see all of the HTML, too, otherwise we're just taking shots in the dark. Please provide a working demo reproducing the current nav menu.

Comment: please add jsfiddle of example image does not help

Comment: An in page Stack Snippet is preferable to a JSFiddle, the fewer outside resources users have to follow and depend on to understand your problem the more likely you get answers.

Comment: I added all of the codes please help me now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move CSS menu to right of screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907896/move-css-menu-to-right-of-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You should add some margin-left to your css. As you have not provided your full HTML I cannot say which attribute exactly needs the stylling.
I think you should add `margin-left` to your menus to increase space between them or to the parent `div` for shifting the whole navbar to the right. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that when you ask how to move them to the right that the ultimate goal is to center the navigation elements inside the blue-green field that is `<nav>`.

You might also be asking to align the navigation items to the right side of the blue-green field, I've addressed that in my second code snippet.

#### Center Nav Items

A common way to center something is to move it to the `left` by `50%` and then pull it back 50% of it's width with `transform`. In order for this to work you'll need to make your `<ul>` not take up 100% of its parent element. You can do this a number of ways, for simplicity I have set it to `display: inline-block;`.

This solution will allow you to add/remove `<li>` and still be centered in `<nav>`.

```css
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateX( -50%);
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a:link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #2da399;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #494949;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

nav ul ul li {
    min-width: 170px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
}

/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */

nav li>a:after {
    content: ' +';
}
nav li>a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}
.menu {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #2da399;
}
```

```html
<!--Main Navigation-->
<div class='menu-wrapper'>
 <div class='menu'>
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/kontakta-mig.html'>Hem</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nyheter </a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/afghanistan.html'>Afghanistan</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/sverige-och-e.html'>Sverige</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Världen</a></li>
            </ul>        
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Vetenskap
</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
              <li><a href='https://www.facebook.com/thevoiceofafghanistan/'>Kemi
</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Fysik </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Matte</a>
             <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Matte 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 3</a>
                        <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Matte 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Hjälpmedel
</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>فناوری </a></li>    
            <li><a href='#'>اجتمائی </a></li>
   <li><a href='#'> سیاست</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>تاریخ </a></li>
   <li><a href=''>کلاس ها</a></li>
   <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/'>صفحه اصلی </a></li>        
  </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
  </div>
```

I noticed you included a little more CSS than what was being used by your markup so I removed it.

#### Align Nav Items to Right

If you are looking to align the navigation to the right side instead of the left side you can float the `<ul>` to the right. The only catch here is that you will need to clear the float so you can see the background color of `.menu`. I used the poor man's clearfix, `overflow: hidden;` but you could use the more modern option of the [Micro Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```css
nav ul {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a:link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #2da399;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #494949;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

nav ul ul li {
    min-width: 170px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
}

/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */

nav li>a:after {
    content: ' +';
}
nav li>a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}
.menu {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #2da399;
  overflow: hidden; /* Clearfix that allows the background of <nav> to be seen with floated child elements. */
}
```

```html
<!--Main Navigation-->
<div class='menu-wrapper'>
 <div class='menu'>
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/kontakta-mig.html'>Hem</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Nyheter </a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/afghanistan.html'>Afghanistan</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/p/sverige-och-e.html'>Sverige</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Världen</a></li>
            </ul>        
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Vetenskap
</a>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
              <li><a href='https://www.facebook.com/thevoiceofafghanistan/'>Kemi
</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Fysik </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Matte</a>
             <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Matte 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Matte 3</a>
                        <!-- Third Tier Drop Down -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#'>Matte 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#'>Hjälpmedel
</a></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>فناوری </a></li>    
            <li><a href='#'>اجتمائی </a></li>
   <li><a href='#'> سیاست</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>تاریخ </a></li>
   <li><a href=''>کلاس ها</a></li>
   <li><a href='https://thevoiceofafghanistan.blogspot.se/'>صفحه اصلی </a></li>        
  </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set your nav ul li width to 100/number of items. and it will spread your menu items equally across the bar, removing the gap on the right as much as possible.

You can remove the space between inline block elements as you like by setting margin-right property accordingly.

Replace old nav ul li with this code:

```
nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
background-color: #2da399;
width:11%;
margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Doing the menu this way will allow your menu to wrap into various screen widths fully.

Comment: What's with the arbitrary units. Doesn't seem very flexible.

Comment: I agree it could use a re-write. But you're using a relative unit inside a fixed width element. The navigation items won't be consistently positioned withing the `<nav>` as the viewport size changes, i.e. try 1200px vs 1600px. I'm assuming the OP wants all navigation items inside `<nav>` at all times, your solution does not do this. Using a fixed width value for `left` would be an improvement. If centering is the ultimate goal then centering the content of `<ul>` inside of `<nav>` without using specific units would be ideal.

Comment: Your new CodePen reverses the order of the navigation items. Also, there's superfluous styling for `<nav>`. No need to float it and `<nav>` is a block element by default so it'll take up 100% of it's parent by default. No use in this example to set width to `100%;` or `100vw;`. Since it has floated content you will need to clear it.

Comment: Wen't with a completely new approach I see, though there's issues with this one as well. `inline-block` elements produce a space around them. In the end `10x 10% = greater than 100%` and items will wrap. Sorry to be bust your nuts so much.

Comment: No problem, I am new and just trying to help as much as I can.